# from .pysoem import * ImportError: DLL load failed:

Tags: python, dll, module, pycharm, importerror

- Windows 10 64
- Pycharm 2022.1.2
- Python 3.6

Last week I worked with the 'pysoem' module and had no problem.
But now I have the following stacktrace :

```
from .pysoem import *
ImportError: DLL load failed"
```

others library are imported correctly.

Does somebody know how fix it? I tried to reinstall PyCharm, add files MSVCP71.DLL and MSVCR71.DLL but it did not help.

Could TortoiseSVN be responsible (I made a 'commit' this week)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That's all the error? How did you install the package? Try installing https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145.

Comment: Yes, that's all error. I have installed Visual C++ Redistributable. 
Solution to fix a problem is instalation Npcap, thank.

Answer (score 0):

Installing *[NPcap](https://npcap.com/#download)* with **API compatible mode** solved this issue for me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35083974)